# How could a datetime.timedelta object be manipulated to allow it to be styled and printed in a manner similar to that for a datetime.datetime object?

Tags: python, datetime, printing, timedelta

I have a function that can be used to print a `datetime.datetime` object in a specified style. I want to be able to print in similar styles the information contained in a `datetime.timedelta` object. How could the `datetime.timedelta` object be manipulated such that it can be styled easily, like by using the function that's already defined?

My code is below (and the answer should be around 82 days, 14 hours).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import datetime

def main():

    print("current time UTC:\n")
    print(
        style_datetime_object(
            datetime_object = datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
            style = "HH hours MM minutes SS seconds day DD month YYYY"
        )
    )

    year_ICHEP_2016  = 2016
    month_ICHEP_2016 = 8
    day_ICHEP_2016   = 3
    datetime_object_ICHEP_2016_time = datetime.datetime(
        year_ICHEP_2016,
        month_ICHEP_2016,
        day_ICHEP_2016
    )
    datetime_object_current_time_UTC = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    datetime_object_current_time_UTC_to_ICHEP_2016_time =\
        datetime_object_ICHEP_2016_time - datetime_object_current_time_UTC

    # insert magic to style datetime.timedelta
    # `datetime_object_current_time_UTC_to_ICHEP_2016_time' using function
    # `style_datetime_object`
    #
    # print(
    #     style_datetime_object(
    #         datetime_object = datetime_object_current_time_UTC_to_ICHEP_2016_time,
    #         style = "HH hours MM minutes SS seconds day DD month YYYY"
    #     )
    # )

def style_datetime_object(
    datetime_object = None,
    style           = "YYYY-MM-DDTHHMMZ"
    ):
    # filename safe
    if style == "YYYY-MM-DDTHHMMZ":
        return datetime_object.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H%MZ")
    # filename safe with seconds
    elif style == "YYYY-MM-DDTHHMMSSZ":
        return datetime_object.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H%M%SZ")
    # filename safe with seconds and microseconds
    elif style == "YYYY-MM-DDTHHMMSSMMMMMMZ":
        return datetime_object.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H%M%S%fZ")
    # elegant
    elif style == "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS UTC":
        return datetime_object.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%SZ")
    # UNIX time in seconds with second fraction
    elif style == "UNIX time S.SSSSSS":
        return (datetime_object -\
            datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)).total_seconds()
    # UNIX time in seconds rounded
    elif style == "UNIX time S":
        return int((datetime_object -\
            datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)).total_seconds())
    # human-readable date
    elif style == "day DD month YYYY":
        return datetime_object.strftime("%A %d %B %Y")
    # human-readable time and date
    elif style == "HH:MM day DD month YYYY":
        return datetime_object.strftime("%H:%M %A %d %B %Y")
    # human-readable time with seconds and date
    elif style == "HH:MM:SS day DD month YYYY":
        return datetime_object.strftime("%H:%M:%S %A %d %B %Y")
    # human-readable date with time with seconds
    elif style == "day DD month YYYY HH:MM:SS":
        return datetime_object.strftime("%A %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S")
    # human-readable-audible time with seconds and date
    elif style == "HH hours MM minutes SS seconds day DD month YYYY":
        return datetime_object.strftime("%H hours %M minutes %S seconds %A %d %B %Y")
    # human-readable days, hours and minutes
    elif style == "DD:HH:MM":
        return datetime_object.strftime("%d:%H:%M")
    # human-readable days, hours, minutes and seconds
    elif style == "DD:HH:MM:SS":
        return datetime_object.strftime("%d:%H:%M:%S")
    # human-readable time with seconds
    elif style == "HH:MM:SS":
        return datetime_object.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    # human-readable-audible time with seconds
    elif style == "HH hours MM minutes SS seconds":
        return datetime_object.strftime("%H hours %M minutes %S seconds")
    # filename safe
    else:
        return datetime_object.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H%MZ")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: No, there is no already defined function to do this.

Comment: Your `style_datetime_object` is overly verbose, why not use a dictionary to map to `strftime()` formats? That covers 99% of your `if..elif` cases.

Comment: Couldn't you just add a datetime object at unix time 0 to it?